# How do I substitute all characters between a delimiter

Tags: regex, pcre

Sorry if the title isn't very clear.

Hi, i have a multi-line string that is enclosed between `----` characters like so:

```
----
line-1
line-2
line-3
line-4
----
```

Now I need to capture the text in between these `----` characters.

I'm currently using the following regex: `/^----$\n([^-]+)\n^----$/m`, then I use the `$1` code to get the text in the back-reference. The problem is the `[^-]` doesn't allow dashes in my string. If I remove the `[^-]`, then  the `----` at the end gets captured by the capturing group.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: For every [tag:regex] question, you really should also tag with a dialect (e.g. [tag:pcre], [tag:python], [tag:javascript], [tag:sed]...)

Comment: The easiest is [`^-{4}$(.*?)^-{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/eM5iG3/1) (with DOTALL and MULTILINE modifier)

Comment: There's no need to do it with regex IMO. You can simply extract the content using substring function (find begin of `----`, find begin of next `----`) in whatever language you are working with.

Comment: @Alex My script doesn't have a string with a fixed amount of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
/^----\n([\s\S]*)\n----$/
```

`[\s\S]` matches any character including newline.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vQ5nP0/1)

Comment: Thank you! I'll just adjust that a bit and it'll be usable.